# Infinite Loop in My Exception Handling?

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to validate a user's input on a menu. Options are 1, 2, 3, and 4. I'm trying to handle the `InputMismatchException` error when they enter in a letter. I can't see what I'm doing wrong to make my code get stuck in an infinite loop.

```
    System.out.println("What will be your starting balance?");

    double startingBalance =0;
    boolean check = false;
    while(!check) {
        try {
            startingBalance = input.nextDouble();
            check = true;   
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input!");
            //startingBalance = 0;
            //e.printStackTrace();
            //check = false;
        }
    }
```

It looks like it get into the catch part, but loops through that repeatedly instead of going back to the try. I tried doing `input.nextDouble();`

to clear input buffer, but did nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `input.nextLine();` to clear your Scanner in your catch block:

```
while (!check) {
    try {
        startingBalance = input.nextDouble();
        check = true;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input!");
        input.nextLine();//this will clear your Scanner and repeat again
    }
}
```

> Can I ask why you used nextLine() as opposed to nextDouble() ?

because `nextLine` move the Scanner to the next line

Comment: Ah, that fixed my problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: Can I ask why you used nextLine() as opposed to nextDouble() ?

Comment: I understand. Thanks for clairifying! I will validate it. I need to wait 10 minutes to do so first.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set boolean check = false after first check and also use input.nestLine()